# Extend an image with imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have an image with dimensions x and y.
I want to use imagick to extend the image to x and y+10.
There is an example of achieving this here:

http://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/edgeExtend

The code example shows how to extend horizontally, but not vertically.

When I use the example for extending horizontally it works:

```
function EdgeExtendHorizontal(&$img)
{
$originalWidth=$img->getImageWidth();
$desiredWidth=$originalWidth+120;
$Factor=$originalWidth/$desiredWidth; 
$Offset=($desiredWidth-$originalWidth)/2;
$img->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_MIRROR);
$img->sampleimage($desiredWidth,$img->getImageHeight());
$points=array($Factor,0,0,1,$Offset,0);
$img->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_AFFINEPROJECTION,$points,false);
}
```

[image]

When, however, I try to switch the parameters so that the image is extended vertically, it does not work:

```
function EdgeExtendVertical(&$img)
{
global $LanguageName;
$originalHeight=$img->getImageHeight();
$desiredHeight=$originalHeight+100;
$Factor=$originalHeight/$desiredHeight; 
$Offset=($desiredHeight-$originalHeight)/2;
$img->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_MIRROR);
$img->sampleimage($img->getImageWidth(),$desiredHeight);
$points=array(0,$Factor,0,1,0,$Offset);
$img->distortImage(Imagick::DISTORTION_AFFINEPROJECTION,$points,false);
}
```

[image]

Modifying the points array as follows does bring a result:

```
$points=array($Factor,0,0,1,0,$Offset);
```

[image]

But now the image is inexplicably extended both vertically and horizontally

Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on the structure of the points array so that the image is exteneded vertically only.

Thanks!

Cymro

Comment: Prynhawn Da! I haven't really played with imagick too much, so off the bat, I'm not a massive help, but mainly just wanted to comment as you're the first Welsh person I've seen on StackOverflow. Anyway, this line looks odd to me in comparison to the first example where the parameters are the other way around? `$img->sampleimage($img->getImageWidth(),$desiredHeight);`

Comment: Diolch Alex. *Extend Horiztonally*: $img->sampleimage($desiredWidth,$img->getImageHeight()); *Extend Vertically*: $img->sampleimage($img->getImageWidth(),$desiredHeight);

Comment: So you are not only extending, but you also want a mirroring sort of effect for what goes into the new extra pixel extension?

Comment: Mirroring is only important as a means to fill in the extended space. As shown in the example above: phpimagick.com/Tutorial/edgeExtend. In the final version, no mirroring will be visible. The mirroring in my post serves only to illustrate the point that I can't yet get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest general way to extending width, height or both at once (PHP >= 5.4):

```
$im = new Imagick ("myfile.png");
$im->setImageVirtualPixelMethod (imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_MIRROR);
list ($width, $height) = array_values ($im->getImageGeometry ());
$extend_width = 0;
$extend_height = 100;
$new_width = $width + $extend_width;
$new_height = $height + $extend_height;
$extend_width /= 2;
$extend_height /= 2;
$im->setImageArtifact ("distort:viewport", "{$new_width}x$new_height-$extend_width-$extend_height");
$im->distortImage (imagick::DISTORTION_SCALEROTATETRANSLATE, [0], false);
$im->writeImage (getcwd () . "/my_extended_image.png");
```

For PHP < 5.4 replace the line beginning with $im->distortImage () with:

```
$im->distortImage (imagick::DISTORTION_SCALEROTATETRANSLATE, array (0), false);
```

Let me know if this doesn't work! Cheers, Lee